# Kotlin expression evaluates to true in if but still goes to else

Tags: android, kotlin, conditional-statements

I have an android application that has a library module. This library module has a build type. I define this in its build.gradle

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        create("full") {
            debuggable true
            buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_TYPE", "\"full\""
        }
   }
```

To begin I clean and rebuild.

[In the screenshot you can see that the BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE is full](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJ4J8.png)

[Even though this expression should evaluate to true, it goes to the else branch.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyXo7.png)

[Here is the evaluator result which is true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7n8s.png)

- I am unsure why in the second screenshot, but when I press the button that fires this function, those breakpoints become disabled.
- Android Gradle Plugin Version 8.0.1
- Gradle Version 8.0
- minSdk: 2 targetSdk: 33 jvmTarget
- Kotlin Version: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.20
- I tried to set the BUILD_TYPE without the escape characters but got the error

```
com\..\..\BuildConfig.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
  public static final String BUILD_TYPE = full;
                                          ^
  symbol:   variable full
  location: class BuildConfig
```

Comment: How are you running the code? The value is currently "full" in the compiler because of whatever configuration is currently selected in the IDE, but you are not necessary building that flavor to run and test.

Comment: Under the Build Variants section in Android Studio, I select "debug" for the main application, and "full" for the library. I then Clean -> Rebuild -> Run "myapplication". I did not want to use flavors since I don't want the main application to have to implement for its flavors since its a library

Comment: @Tenfour04 It does appear in the logcat that the value is "debug". Why would it be set as that in the IDE but not built correctly? How do I build it correctly? 
15:27:15.212  4642-4642  TAG          com.example.myapplication            D  debug